# Display Suite changes disappear, clear cache restores

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, display-suite

I am using Display Suite to add a php button/link to the page for a single content-type. It works great. The title and the custom field (the button) appear as expected.

After some time, less than a day I believe, the title and button are no longer visible.

Checking the content type, the setup for the display has not changed.
Clear Cache All fixes the problem...for a day or so.

I would like the Display Suite custom field and the Title to stay in place on the page.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2066359) in the Display Suite issue queue which describes similar behaviour. Perhaps it can be of help...

Comment: I'm trying upping both those settings in the Drupal settings file (this client is on a shared server). If it works I'll post as an answer unless you want to do it @SidneyGijzen

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Doug. Fingers crossed; I hope that it works for you. I would like to summarize the d.o. issue in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your case resembles the problem described in [this drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2066359). One of the module developers thinks it is mostly related to out of memory exceptions.

A possible solution, [described here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2066359#comment-8773451), is to increase the following PHP settings:

- memory_limit to 192MB
- max_input_vars to 2000

Comment: Thanks for this. The pages ran a bit longer (over a day) but then the button and title disappeared again. In addition, I'm not getting entries in my PHP Error log, so it may not be a memory problem. I'm still working on tracking it down, but this didn't fix it.  The running longer may be because of the holiday, if there was less traffic.  Still seems like SOME kind of a memory or resource issue, but not sure yet.

Comment: Hello Doug, you're welcome. It's a pity it didn't work out. Did you already try to post an issue in the Display Suite issue queue on drupal.org?

Comment: Yes. The owner says it must be an environment issue. Which isn't helpful, but I get that it can't all be his problem. I'll see if I can figure it out and post here.